# What is the Iddah (waiting period) after Khula for a girl living with her parents for last one year?

Tags: iddah

My sister is living with my parents for last one year Jan 2014- Jan 2015. She applied for khula from her husband on September 2014. She got Khula on 27th Jan 2015. What will be her iddah period.

Answer (score -2):

If the marriage was consummated then the husband agreed to give Khula to the wife, the iddah would be one menstrual cycle. This is based on the Khula of the wife of Thabi bin Qais.

If there was no sexual intercourse, then there would be no iddah.

Comment: One menstrual cycle from when?  Separation?  Application for Khula?  Award of Khula?

Comment: " husband agreed to give Khula to the wife...
"